# Throw and catch std::string

Tags: c++, string, class, throw

I made strange code, but surprisingly it works. But now I don't know what I throw and how can I catch it:

```
class Date {
private:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    int daysPerMonth[];
public:
    Date( int day, int month, int year ) {
        int daysPerMonth[12] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

        if(isValidDate(day, month, year)) {
            this->day = day;
            this->month = month;
            this->year = year;
        } else {
            throw std::string("No valid input date numbers...");//what i throw???
        }
    }
```

Please help me with code.

Comment: What you would like to understand? What that code suppose to do?

Comment: you are throwing std::string(), catch by `const std::string&` or by value `std::string`. hope you are not trolling :-)

Comment: No, not trolling. Im just new to c++))

Comment: [try this link](http://www.exceptionsafecode.com/)

Comment: "I made strange code But surprisingly it works" -> This was great, I put that onto my list of quoations :D / edit: I found that so great, I added it to my profile page.

Comment: If you throw `std::runtime_error` then parent code can catch `std::exception` and get your exception, without having to add extra exception handlers just for your code.

Comment: For completeness, you don't have to throw `std::string()` in order to have an error message in the exception; `std::runtime_error()` from `<stdexcept>` also takes a string parameter for its constructor (as does anything derived from that class), and you can extract it in the `catch` block using `.what()`. Semantically a bit "cleaner" than throwing `std::string` IMHO, especially once you start building an exception hierarchy (which might become a bit tricky with `std::string` as a base).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Like this below (Not compiled):-

```
class Date {
private:
int day;
int month;
int year;
int daysPerMonth[];
public:
Date( int day, int month, int year ) {
    int daysPerMonth[12] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

    if(isValidDate(day, month, year)) 
    {
        this->day = day;
        this->month = month;
        this->year = year;
    } else {
        throw std::string("No valid input date numbers...");//what i throw???
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
 try{
    Date d(55,223,0122);
  }
 catch(std::string &e)
 {
    // Do necessary handling
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you can throw objects of any type. Usually that is `std::exception` or a type derived from it, but it can be anything else. For instance `CException` in MFC or `_com_error` have nothing to do with `std::exception`. Regardless what you throw you must catch the same. (You cannot throw a `std::string` and catch a `std::exception`.)

Answer (score 1):

C++ allows you to `throw` values of any type (including fundamental types).

```
try {
    throw 42;
} catch(int e) {
    std::cout << "Caught: " << e << "\n";
}
```

But as with many other things in C++, just because you can do it, does not mean you *should* do it.

The [usual advice](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/what-to-throw.html) here is to throw dedicated exception objects deriving from `std::exception` in some way. That is, if a types that are thrown should not be used in other contexts. If you want to associate a certain value with an exception, build an exception wrapper class that contains that value as a member, instead of throwing the value's type directly.

The rationale for this advice is that you want to build an exception hierarchy that allows catching at different layers of generality: If I'm not interested in the exact kind of exception I just catch `std::exception`; if I only want to handle certain kinds of errors, I instead catch a derived class further down the exception hierarchy.

Such exception hierarchies are much easier to maintain and reason about if you keep exception types distinct from the other types used in your program. Also, this guideline makes it less tempting for people to abuse exceptions as glorified return values, which is something you should never do.